# Find a string in python files using Python

Tags: string, python-2.7, path, glob, os.path

I very new to python. I am trying to find all python files that hav the string "DATASOURCE" inside them and to print the path name of the files. I'm using this code:

```
import os,glob

os.chdir(r"G:\PROJECTS\menofim_3_5\gis")
for file in glob.glob('*.py'):
    with open(file) as f:
        contents = f.read()
    if 'DATASOURCE' in contents:
        print file
```

I only get this result:

```
>>> 
findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths-dwg.py
Remove FGB by dataSource excluding specific mxd.py
SelectLayerByLocation2.py
SelectLayerByLocation3.py
>>>
```

I have succeeded in printing the file name, but I don't know how to print the path name of the files.

Comment: Is this wrong? Explain what did you expect. By the way, you don't close a file in your code when done with it.

Comment: @АндрейЧереваткин: You don't need to explicitly close the file when using `with`

Comment: Ah, right. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to connect the dirname to the filename:

```
import os, glob

dirname = r"G:\PROJECTS\menofim_3_5\gis"
os.chdir(dirname)
for filename in glob.glob('*.py'):
    with open(filename) as f:
        contents = f.read()
    if 'DATASOURCE' in contents:
        print os.path.join(dirname, filename)
        print file
```

Comment: Raymond Hettinger, change the last line into "print filename"